# Ipad and Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

For the latest version of IOS8, I have my app mostly in portrait mode but few screens where user needs to write text where keyboard populates , i want user to be able to switch to landscape mode. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method for those specific controllers and specify which orientations are allowed.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```